# boost thread_group infinite loop

Tags: c++, boost, infinite-loop, boost-thread, threadgroup

I am using boost and trying to create a basic thread_group that will perform their tasks and exit. Here's what my code looks like:

```
boost::thread_group threads;
void InputThread()
{
    int counter = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        cout << "iteration #" << ++counter << " Press Enter to stop" << endl;

        try
        {
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));
        }
        catch(boost::thread_interrupted&)
        {
            cout << "Thread is stopped" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int iterator;
    char key_pressed;
    boost::thread t[NUM_THREADS];

    for(iterator = 0; iterator < NUM_THREADS; iterator++)
    {
        threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&InputThread)) ;
        cout << "iterator is: " << iterator << endl;

           // Wait for Enter to be pressed      
        cin.get(key_pressed);

        // Ask thread to stop
        t[iterator].interrupt();

    }
    // Join all threads
    threads.join_all();

    return 0;
}
```

I started with two threads and fall in an infinite loop after both the threads are done with their jobs. Something like below:

```
iterator is: 0
iteration #1 Press Enter to stop
iteration #2 Press Enter to stop

iterator is: 1
iteration #1 Press Enter to stop
iteration #3 Press Enter to stop
iteration #2 Press Enter to stop

iteration #4 Press Enter to stop
iteration #3 Press Enter to stop
iteration #5 Press Enter to stop
iteration #4 Press Enter to stop
iteration #6 Press Enter to stop
iteration #5 Press Enter to stop
iteration #7 Press Enter to stop
^C
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no relationship drawn between your `boost::thread t[]` and `boost::thread_group threads;`.

So `t[iterator].interrupt();` has no effect on the threads spawned by `threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&InputThread)) ;`.

Instead do:

```
std::vector<boost::thread *> thread_ptrs;
// ...

    thread_ptrs.push_back(threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&InputThread)));

    // ...

    thread_ptrs[iterator].interrupt();
```

Aside: the name "iterator" is often used for types and makes a poor value to iterate over.  Use `i` or some other idiomatic name for this value.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the issue. I will need better understanding of thread_group though.

Comment: @user2816953 If you're satisfied with the answer, please upvote and/or accept the answer accordingly.

Comment: I already accepted the answer but still do not have enough reputation to upvote. I just signed up two days back. When I get there, I will return your favor of answering by voting up :)